# How to send Email verification in react native firebase and verify?

Tags: react-native, authentication, email, email-verification

I am using react native android  firebase i want to send email on user email for verification of email of user and after verification the user creates in firebase

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` definitely has a method to send verification email: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#sendPasswordResetEmail You can simply call this method with the email provided by the user.